# Chrome issue with embedded Google Maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

I'm using a touch screen desktop computer and I've set up one of the basic Google Maps examples on their website. When I try and pan in Chrome, it doesn't work, but in Firefox it does. Pinch to zoom does not work in either of them, but at maps.google.com, everything is functioning normally with the touch screen.

**UPDATE**

This issue was handled in the bug

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35824421

and was solved in version 3.27 of Google Maps JavaScript API in December 2016.

Comment: sadly, chrome does not support pinch to zoom. it is the fault of the browser not your code if any.

Comment: How does it work with maps.google.com ?

Comment: can you tell me which version of google maps you are running?

Comment: I just went to maps.google.com and pinch to zoom works, but not with an embedded map.

Comment: I've just come accross this - how annoying!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by simulating my own touch capability using JQuery Mobile(`vmousemove` event). Replace `#map-element` with the the name of the element containing the actual map. Also set `map` to the Google Maps object that allows you to pan. It works pretty well.

Note: I only needed this to work on Chrome, so I haven't tried any other browsers.

```
            var mouseIsDown = false;
            var oldX = 0; var oldY = 0;
            var newX = 0; var newY = 0;
            var toid;
            $("#map-element").on("vmousemove vmousedown", function(e) {
                clearTimeout(toid);
                if (e.target.id == "map-div") {
                    if (e.type == "vmousedown") { // resets all values
                        oldX = 0; oldY = 0; newX = 0; newY = 0;
                        mouseIsDown = true;
                    }

                if (mouseIsDown) {
                    if (newX != 0 && newY != 0) {
                        oldX = newX;
                        oldY = newY;

                        newX = e.pageX;
                        newY = e.pageY;

                        map.panBy(-(newX - oldX), -(newY - oldY));
                    } else {
                        newX = e.pageX;
                        newY = e.pageY;
                    }       

                }

            toid = setTimeout(function() {
                mouseIsDown = false;
            }, 100);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a issue with Google Map on Chrome and Windows 7, 8 (see [#6425](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6425)).

Another solution is to use hammer.js touch gesture javascript libary to recreate pinch feature.

```js
var map;

function initialize() {

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    zoom: 8,
    center: {
      lat: -34.397,
      lng: 150.644
    }
  });

  var mc = new Hammer(document.getElementById('map-canvas'));
  mc.get('pinch').set({
    enable: true
  });
  var scale, zoom;
  mc.on('pinchstart', function(ev) {
    scale = ev.scale;
    zoom = map.getZoom();
  });
  mc.on('pinch', function(ev) {
    if (scale) {
      var delta = (scale - ev.scale);
      map.setZoom(Math.round(zoom - delta));
    }
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
 html,
 body,
 #map-canvas {
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
  <script src="https://hammerjs.github.io/dist/hammer.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

This only handle pinch gesture and may need some adjustments.

See also my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28661844/touch-events-not-working-with-google-maps-in-angular/31023464#31023464) for a workaround using user Agent spoofing