# pinch&zooming issue on google maps using microsoft surface touch screen's Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Recently I am developing google maps based web site.
It works on most devices, but after I installed Chrome browser on ms surface touch screen, I can  not pinch & zoom google maps by fingers.
But I can do such actions on maps.google.com using chrome browser.
I have to use chrome browser, not other browsers.
For now only IE works regards on pinch and zooming on surface pro.

How can I solve this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is a issue with Google Map on Chrome and Windows 7, 8 (see [#6425](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6425)).

See my answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28661844/touch-events-not-working-with-google-maps-in-angular/31023464#31023464) and [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17153478/chrome-issue-with-embedded-google-maps/31028787#31028787).

Workarounds are :

- recreating pinch gesture
- using User Agent spoofing to switch to a mobile like gmap instead of desktop gmap.